# hue saturation value (HSV) colormap wheel matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I'm plotting an image which depicts the directional orientations via the color code. According to the literature it is usually coded by using hue saturation value (HSV)color space represented with a 2pi wheel. How do I create a HSV colorbar wheel?

I've to create it in this way but I cannot figure out how to make the whole 2pi wheel with the 1pi periodicity.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

display_axes = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9], projection='polar')

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(0.5* np.pi, 1.5 * np.pi)
quant_steps = 2056
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(display_axes,
                               cmap=cm.get_cmap('hsv', quant_steps),
                               norm=norm,
                               orientation='horizontal')
cb.outline.set_visible(False)                                 
display_axes.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

I'd like to obtain something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a color wheel you need to go around the complete circle, from 0 to 2pi or from pi to 3pi etc.

Then you would probably want to create new colormap which consists of twice the original one.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

display_axes = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], projection='polar')

quant_steps = 256
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(0, 2 * np.pi)
hsv = cm.get_cmap('hsv', quant_steps)
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(hsv(np.tile(np.linspace(0,1,quant_steps),2)))

cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(display_axes,
                               cmap=cmap,
                               norm=norm,
                               orientation='horizontal')
cb.outline.set_visible(False)                                 
display_axes.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, I was completely missing the np.tile hack.